# SELECT latest record from a SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains the terms of payment for a product. I want to get the latest terms for that product. In the query below it returns all the terms since my application went into production. I only need the latest term for that product.

```
SELECT
   dbo.FinishProduct.id,
   dbo.PaymentTerm.id,
   dbo.PaymentTerm.terms,
   dbo.PaymentTerm.type
FROM
   dbo.PaymentTerm
INNER JOIN
   dbo.FinishProduct ON (dbo.PaymentTerm.finishProductId = dbo.FinishProduct.id) 
WHERE
   finishproduct.id = 39
```

My `PaymentTerm` table has PK `id` and it has date when it was created and updated, like this:

```
id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
created DATETIME,
lastUpdated DATETIME,
```

Comment: what is the column based on which you decide the payment term as the latest one? what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: How do you know which one is the latest?

Comment: Do you have a field which could be used to sort the PaymentTerm in order?   Like a date or timestamp field created_at column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put orderby clause on lastUpdated field in query and get the top 10 or more latest record accordingly as follows

```
SELECT TOP 10  FP.id, PT.id, PT.terms, PT.type
  FROM dbo.PaymentTerm PT
  INNER JOIN dbo.FinishProduct FP ON PT.finishProductId = FP.id 
  WHERE FP.id=39
  ORDER BY lastUpdated desc
```

Or if you need to get all records from one day back to current date use DateDiff in built function like this

```
SELECT FP.id, PT.id, PT.terms, PT.type
  FROM dbo.PaymentTerm PT
  INNER JOIN dbo.FinishProduct FP ON PT.finishProductId = FP.id 
  WHERE FP.id=39 AND DateDiff(DAY,lastUpdated, GETDATE()) <= 1
```

Comment: I tried something like this but it returns the wrong row

  `SELECT TOP 1  FP.id, PT.id, PT.terms, PT.type 
  FROM dbo.PaymentTerm PT 
  INNER JOIN dbo.FinishProduct FP ON PT.finishProductId = FP.id  
  WHERE FP.id=39 
  ORDER BY PT.lastUpdated desc`